# Javascript Regex String Replace Not Replacing

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following function, but my string is never replaced?  What am I doing wrong?

```
function customRegex(){
      return function(myString,replacement,myValue){
        var s = myString;
        var rgx = new RegExp("/("+replacement+")/,gi");
        myString = myString.replace(rgx, myValue);
        return myString;
    }
  }

  var reg = customRegex();
  console.log( reg("This is the worst!","worst","best"));
  //This is always returning the original string?
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the regex declaration. You seem to have tried adding regex delimiters, but `RegExp` constructor accepts a *string* when you build a dynamic pattern, so, the `/` are treated as literal symbols in the string pattern. The regex modifiers `gi` should be passed as a second string argument.

Use

```
var rgx = new RegExp(replacement,"gi");
```

See the demo below:

```js
function customRegex(){
      return function(myString,replacement,myValue){
        var s = myString;
        var rgx = new RegExp(replacement,"gi");
        myString = myString.replace(rgx, myValue);
        return myString;
    }
  }

  var reg = customRegex();
  console.log( reg("This is the worst!","worst","best"));
```

Also, if your search pattern can contain special regex metacharacters, you will need to escape them. See [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) SO thread.